# MPI deadlock with collective functions

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm writing a program in C++ with MPI library. There is a deadlock occurring only one nodes works! I am not using send or receive collective operations but only the two collective functions(`MPI_Allreduce` and `MPI_Bcast`). 
If there is node waits other node to send something or receive I don't actually understand what cause this deadlock.

```
void ParaStochSimulator::first_reacsimulator() {
    SimulateSingleRun();
}

double ParaStochSimulator::deterMinTau() {
    //calcualte minimum tau for this process
    l_nLocalMinTau = calc_tau(); //min tau for each node
    MPI_Allreduce(&l_nLocalMinTau, &l_nGlobalMinTau, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
    //min tau for all nodes
    //check if I have the min value
    if (l_nLocalMinTau <= l_nGlobalMinTau && m_nCurrentTime < m_nOutputEndPoint) {
        FireTransition(m_nMinTransPos);
        CalculateAllHazardValues(); 
    }
    return l_nGlobalMinTau;
}

void ParaStochSimulator::SimulateSingleRun() {
    //prepare a run
    PrepareRun();
    while ((m_nCurrentTime < m_nOutputEndPoint) && IsSimulationRunning()) {
        deterMinTau();
        if (mnprocess_id == 0) { //master
            SimulateSingleStep();
            std::cout << "current time:*****" << m_nCurrentTime << std::endl;
            broad_casting(m_nMinTransPos);
            MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, l_nMinplacesPos.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            //std::cout << "size of mani place :" << l_nMinplacesPos.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, l_nMinplacesPos.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    PostProcessRun();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your "master" process is executing A MPI_Bcast, all the other are still running your loop, then entering deterMinTau, then executing MPI_Allreduce.

This is a deadlock because you master node is waiting for all the nodes to execute a Brodcast and all the other nodes are waiting for the master node to execute a Reduce.

I believe what you are looking for is :

```
void ParaStochSimulator::SimulateSingleRun() {
    //prepare a run
    PrepareRun();
    while ((m_nCurrentTime < m_nOutputEndPoint) && IsSimulationRunning()) {
        //All the nodes reduce tau at the same time
        deterMinTau();
        if (mnprocess_id == 0) { //master
            SimulateSingleStep();
            std::cout << "current time:*****" << m_nCurrentTime << std::endl;
            broad_casting(m_nMinTransPos);
            //Removed bordcast for master here
        }
        //All the nodes broadcast at every loop iteration
        MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, l_nMinplacesPos.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    PostProcessRun();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately i removed broadcast form the master  and there is still deadlock -_-